# How to determine which task is invoking an unanauthorized call in an ECS cluster running jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I have a situation where SOME task, under an assumed ECS role, is attempting to invoke a "CreateCluster" command and it's being (thankfully) denied!

However, there are 1000s of these invocation per hour and we are really trying to cut down on the noise.

We are running jenkins agents in ECS and SOME job (I assume) is trying to create clusters. I have checked our entire source code repo looking for a culprit and I find nothing. How do I figure out the origin of these calls when it could be any task/container on any host in this ECS cluster? Below is a snip of some athena output to help illustrate

[image]

Comment: Look at cloudtrail events with  the right eventName, they do have sourceIP Addresses, that might help.

Comment: It does. It's a public IP I don't recognize

Comment: I see that the CreateCluster call is invoked with an `assumed-role`. You can look in CloudTrail to find the AssumeRole call that gave these credentials. If Instance credentials were used to acquire these, it can point you to the instance/container.

Comment: @Niobos - thanks - let me try that

Comment: look at the cloudtrail event JSON, you should have a userIdentity element, see if the principalID, arn, sessionIssuer helps you figure out the instance id, taskid or role that was used to create the session and see if that provides a hint of where the call came from. Also see if you can paste the complete error message that might also have a hint of the task/instance-id that made the call. Also if your VPC is private the API source IP might be the one for the NAT gateway.

Comment: I know the instance id - it has an arn and the instance id is one of our cluster hosts. I have already completely inspected the userIdentity - that's the only reason I know it's the cluster. Thanks for the hint though

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:
All of my nodes are docker optimized AMIs - so, they would have the ecs agent installed even if I am not using them in an ECS cluster.

I temporarily gave it access to create a cluster (And it turns out it also wanted to RegisterContainerInstance) and it immediately created a cluster called `default` and registered my 2 docker build nodes and a 3 node I didn't readily recognize (which clued me in). it then registered 3 container instances.

When I look at the one instance I don't recognize I realized that isn't running a docker container on an optimized host and that's when it all came together: The ECS agents on virts, if they aren't part of a cluster, try to make themselves part of a `default` cluster and register themselves.

```
$ aws ecs describe-clusters --profile default --clusters default
{
    "clusters": [
        {
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:882038671278:cluster/default",
            "clusterName": "default",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 3,
            "runningTasksCount": 0,
            "pendingTasksCount": 0,
            "activeServicesCount": 0,
            "statistics": [],
            "tags": [],
            "settings": [
                {
                    "name": "containerInsights",
                    "value": "disabled"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

instances

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --profile default --cluster default \
| jq -r '.containerInstanceArns[]' \
| xargs -L 1 aws ecs describe-container-instances --profile default --container-instances \
| jq -r .containerInstances[].ec2InstanceId
i-0f6e3c0b2e125c46c
i-07c6e10b85ac3bace
i-0619eccf3c2734b64
```

[image]